# How can I return control from my python script to the calling bash script?

Tags: python, bash

I am using a bash script to loop through a configuration file and, based on that, call a python script via ssh. Unfortunately once the Python script does its job and I call `quit` the bash script also gets closed, therefore the calling bash script's loop is terminated prematurely.

Here's my Bash Script

```
target |  grep 'srv:'  | while read l ; do srv $l $SSH ; done

 srv () {
 SSH=$2
 SRV=`echo $1 | awk -F: '{print $2}'`
 STATUS=`echo $1 | awk -F: '{print $3}'`
 open $SSH "srv" $SRV $STATUS
 }
```

then on the remote machine where the python script is called

```
if __name__== "main":
   redirect('./Server.log', 'false')
   conn()
   if sys.argv[1] == "srv":
     ServerState(sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
   quit()
```

So looks like the quit() is also interrupting the script.

Comment: Have you tried removing the quit() statement and letting execution reach the end of the file?

Comment: Does the quit function fire sys.exit(0)? You might try that as well, if Alex's fix doesn't work.

Comment: I've just tried to comment the quit() which is a function to gracefully close the open session with the server.

Anyway, it still behaving in the same way. Could it be the SSH session?
   `open () {
    if [ $1 = "true" ] ; then
   ssh -l "$SSHUSER" "$SSHOST" "$WSLT $PYTH $2 $3 $4;"
    else
 $WLST $PYTH $2 $3 $4
     fi
}`

Comment: I think I need to fork the ssh call...

Answer (score 1):

Nothing that the remote Python script does should be able to kill your `do` loop unless you have done a `set -e` in the local `bash` first to make it sensitive to command failure — in which case it would die only if, as @EOL says, your remote script is hitting an exception and returning a nonzero/error value to SSH which will then die with a nonzero/error code locally.

What happens if you replace `do srv` with `do echo srv` so that you just get a printout of the commands you think you are running? Do you see several `srv` command lines get printed out, and do they have the arguments you expect?

Oh: and, why are you using `open` to allocate a new Linux virtual terminal for every single run of the command? You do not run out of virtual terminals that way?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `quit()` is the function that makes your program stop.

If you can remove the call to `quit()` (i.e. if it does nothing), just remove it.

Otherwise, you can run your Python program by hand (not from a shell script) and see what happens: it is likely that your Python script generates an exception, which makes the shell script stop.  By running your Python program manually with realistic arguments (on the remote machine), you should be able to spot the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to simply return from the main function.